# Group_by HS.Code = 8 character

Tags: r

I am trying to find a way to group Import values grouped by their HS Code (Harmonized codification of Products). I have a dataset with Import values by product at HS10; I want to sum the rows and convert the dataset to Import values by-products at HS8. HS10 means that the code used is 10 character length and HS8 implies that the code used is 8 character length. Before rewriting a new function to resolve this problem, I want to know if there is some package that could solve my issue.

```
Below is a little Head of my dataset:
> head(tun)
   HS.code10 Import
1 1022110000      0
2 1022110005   1051
3 1022999026  19126
4 1041030017   1289
5 1051119007    134
6 1051191000      0
```

And the desired result is:

```
> head(tun)
  HS.code8   Import
1 10221100     1051
2 10229990    19126
3 10410300     1289
4 10511190      134
5 10511910        0
```

I tried Group_by and summarize from the dplyr package but without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the first 8 characters of `HS.code10` in a call to `aggregate` and `sum` the `Import` values.

```
agg <- aggregate(Import ~ substr(HS.code10, 1, 8), tun, sum)
names(agg)[1] <- "HS.code8"
agg
#  HS.code8 Import
#1 10221100   1051
#2 10229990  19126
#3 10410300   1289
#4 10511190    134
#5 10511910      0
```

**Data.**

```
tun <-
structure(list(HS.code10 = c(1022110000L, 1022110005L, 1022999026L, 
1041030017L, 1051119007L, 1051191000L), Import = c(0L, 1051L, 
19126L, 1289L, 134L, 0L)), .Names = c("HS.code10", "Import"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```